# Как звучит данный сценарий аккордеона?

Tags: jquery

Как дословно звучит данный код и что в нём происходит и для чего? Это поможет для корректировки кода. По частям его прочитал со справочником, но в целом не понятна логика создателя.

```
$(function() {
    var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
        this.el = el || {};
        this.multiple = multiple || false;

        // Variables privadas
        var links = this.el.find('.link');
        // Evento
        links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)
    }

    Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
        var $el = e.data.el;
            $this = $(this),
            $next = $this.next();

        $next.slideToggle();
        $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

        if (!e.data.multiple) {
            $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
        };
    }   

    var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
    this.el = el || {};
    this.multiple = multiple || false;

    // Variables privadas
    var links = this.el.find('.link');
    // Evento
    links.on('click', {
      el: this.el,
      multiple: this.multiple
    }, this.dropdown)
  }

  Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
    var $el = e.data.el;
    $this = $(this),
      $next = $this.next();

    $next.slideToggle();
    $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

    if (!e.data.multiple) {
      $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
    };
  }

  var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #2d2c41;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif, Verdana, Tahoma;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  color: #b63b4d;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/** =======================
 * Contenedor Principal
 ===========================*/

h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
h1 a {
  color: #c12c42;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 30px auto 20px;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  color: #4D4D4D;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.accordion li:last-child .link {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.accordion li i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #595959;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
  right: 12px;
  left: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.accordion li.open .link {
  color: #b63b4d;
}
.accordion li.open i {
  color: #b63b4d;
}
.accordion li.open i.fa-chevron-down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
/**
 * Submenu
 -----------------------------*/

.submenu {
  display: none;
  background: #444359;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.submenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e;
}
.submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.submenu a:hover {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Smooth Accordion Dropdown Menu Demo</h1>
<!-- Contenedor -->
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>Web Design<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-code"></i>Coding<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Javascript</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">jQuery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ruby</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>Devices<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Tablet</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Desktop</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Global<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Google</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Bing</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Yahoo</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
```

Создаём "класс" с именем `Accordion` и с конструктором принимающим два параметра - el(JQuery-селектор) и multiple(boolean). внутри конструктора которого делаем следующее:

```
this.el = el || {};
```

Присваиваем свойству `el` либо одноименный элемент переданный как аргумент конструктора, либо если значение аргумента можно приравнять к false(null, undefined, 0, NaN и т.д.) - пустой объект(`{}`). Автору вероятно было лень организовать полноценную проверку, да выдать исключение.

```
this.multiple = multiple || false;
```

Если аргумент multiple можно приравнять к true - присваиваем одноименному свойству это значение. Иначе - присваиваем false. Бессмысленная проверка - вероятно автор написал это на автомате, например, с просони.

```
// Variables privadas
```

Комментарий на испанском "локальные переменные". Вероятней всего автор - мексиканец, либо испанец.

```
var links = this.el.find('.link');
```

Присваиваем переменной `links` элемент с классом `.links`, найденный внутри элемента `$this.el`

```
// Evento
```

Комментарий "событие" на испанском

```
links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)
```

Вешаем обработчик `this.dropdown()` на  событие 'click'. В качестве дополнительных данных передаём объект с свойствами `el` и `multiple`

```
Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
```

Создаём прототип метода класса `dropdown` класса `Accordion`

```
var $el = e.data.el;
  $this = $(this),
  $next = $this.next();
```

Присваиваем локальным переменным `$el`, `$this`, `$next` указатели на значения `e.data.el`(`el` переданный как дополнительные данные), `$(this)`(текущий элемент селектора), и `$this.next()`(элемент следующий за текущим)

```
$next.slideToggle();
```

Вызываем для следующего за текущим элемента метод [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

```
$this.parent().toggleClass('open');
```

Добавляем или удаляем класс `open` у вышестоящего элемента

```
if (!e.data.multiple) {
```

Если `e.data.multiple` можно приравнять к false

```
$el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
```

Находим внутри элемента `$el` элементы с классом `.submenu`, убираем из результата поиска элемент $next(которого там итак не должно быть), вызываем у них метод slideUp(), после чего у их родительского класса удаляем класс `open`

```
var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
```

Создаём экземпляр объекта Accordion, тем самым выполняя его конструктор.

---

Это ужасно написанный код. Вероятно в момент написания, у его автора абсолютно отсутствовали понимание назначения и применения ООП, знание библиотеки jQuery, да и вообще JavaScript'а.

Comment: Сергей, благодарю за ответ!!! Помогите, пожалуйста, с этим вопросом http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483083/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD Пытаюсь сделать хороший аккордеон, но опыта нет, чтобы найти нужное направление. Думаю многим будет очень полезно.